# Reading inverted barcodes in ZXing (ObjC)

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins, zxing

I'm using the ZXing port for Objective-C as a Cordova plugin. It works well, but one issue is that is cannot read inverted barcodes. I've attempted to modify the source to make it possible by either:

1. Using `CIFilter` to invert the image and using its sample data as input for ZXing
2. Modify luminosity values

However, I'm having finding where processing of video frames occurs. Looking through the `zxing-all-in-one.cpp` file, I see plenty of methods where processing could be occurring, however I see similar methods in `CDVBarcodeScanner.mm`, and commenting out method bodies still allows the scanner to function normally.

Basically, I'm simply trying to find a starting point. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an inverted flag on ZXCapture, see that here:

See: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=invert&type=

To detect an inverted barcode you could set that flag.

Psuedocode for instance:

```
ZXCapture *capture = [[ZXCapture alloc] init];
capture.invert = YES;
[capture start];
```

Hope that helps.